# Displaying a UIImageViews image to the size of the actual image

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

How does one set a UIImageview's image to the actual image size rather than filling the view with the image and thus stretching the image(if the image is smaller than the UIImageView's size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to adjust the [contentMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode) property. I suspect to [UIViewContentModeCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewContentModeCenter).

Answer (score 1):

Create the `UIImageView` like this:

```
UIImageView *aImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
```

So the `ImageView` has the size of the image.

I hope my answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're in IB or a Storyboard, click on the Attributes inspector tab after selecting your imageview, look down in the View section (under ImageView) and where it says "mode", change the selection from "scale to fill" (the default) to "center"

I think this is basically the IB equivalent of Tommy's answer, which does the same only programmatically.